# Normal or not that no bounding boxes are shown on tensorboard Images tab when training object detection model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm training an object detection model with Tensorflow (fine tuning from ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8) and monitor the training task with tensorboard. I was expecting in the Images tab of tensorboard that images that are displayed would show a bounding box. What I see though is only images with an orange line drawn above the picture (the same orange that I expect for the bounding box). Am I missing something? Am I right when I say that a bounding box should appear or not? Picture of what I see is joined. Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: As far as I remember: one side of the picture was ground truth, while the other was predictions. Both sides however should display bounding boxes with class names. Maybe your input data is not correctly formatted?

Comment: I answered your question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/85085/95523

Comment: Does any body found solution of it.